# Php / Sql Error in Output Data

Tags: php, sql

**The php:**

```
   <?php
        $pID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        if(!$pID) {
            echo "No pID specified.";
            exit;
        }
        $username = "###";
        $password = "####";
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=###', $username, $password);
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sth = $pdo->prepare('
            SELECT D.name, P.lname, P.fname, P.picpath, P.email, C.info, C.date
              FROM Department D, Professor P, Comment C
             WHERE D.dID = P.dID
             AND P.pID = C.pID;
        ');
        $sth->execute(array(
            $pID
        ));
    ?>
```

**Used in same page:**

```
<?php
                if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
                    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    echo "<img style='float:left;' src='img/profViewIcon.png' alt='Professor {$row['fname']} {$row['lname']} at Drexel' /><h1> <span title='{$row['fname']} {$row['lname']} at Drexel University'> {$row['fname']} {$row['lname']} </h1>";
                    echo "
                    <div class='professor_pic'>
                        <img src='{$row['picpath']}' />
                    </div><!-- /professor_pic -->
                    <div class='professor_desc'>
                        <span class='one' style='float:left; padding:5px 0 0 5px;'><strong>Department:</strong> {$row['name']} </span><br>
                        <span class='two' style='float:left; padding:5px 0 0 5px;'><strong>Email:</strong> {$row['email']} </span><br>
                        <span class='two' style='float:right;'>
                            <strong>Rating:</strong><img src='img/fullStar.png'><img src='img/fullStar.png'><img src='img/fullStar.png'><img src='img/halfStar.png'>
                        </span><br>
                        <span class='two' style='float:left; padding:20px 5px 0 5px; font-size:1.50em;'>
                            <img src='img/commentOnProf.png' class='left' />&nbsp;<a href='#addComment' style='font-weight:bold;'>Write A Comment</a>
                        </span>
                        <span class='two' style='float:right; padding-right:5px;'>
                            <img class='left' width='24' height='24' src='img/posComment.png' /> Positive:18 
                            <img src='img/negComment.png' width='24' height='24' /> Negative:10 
                            <img width='24' height='24' src='img/neuComment.png' />Neutral:5
                        </span>
                    </div><!-- /professor_desc-->
                    <div id='clear'> </div>
                    <div class='professor_comments'>
                                        "; // end echo
                echo "                  
                <h2 style='margin:0; padding:0;'>Recent Comments</h2>
                <div class='comment'>by Anonymous on {$row2['date']}: <br> {$row2['info']} </div>

                    <input type='text' id='addComment' name='addComment' />
                    ";

                } else {
                    echo "No results.";
                }
                unset($sth);
                ?>
?>
```

Why isn't this pulling the fname, lname, etc values??

Its pulling the "By Anonoymous " part, but none of the values. Anyone

Answer (score 0):

I cant be for certain if either of these are part of your issue but i do see a few things:

First of all youre passing a parameter to be bound to the statement when you call `execute`, however there is no placeholder for such a parameter - this should generate an exception about bound parameters i think:

```
 $sth = $pdo->prepare('
            SELECT D.name, P.lname, P.fname, P.picpath, P.email, C.info, C.date
              FROM Department D, Professor P, Comment C
             WHERE D.dID = P.dID
             AND P.pID = C.pID;
        '); 
        $sth->execute(array(
            $pID // there is no placeholder to bind this too!
        ));
```

Secondly unless you omitted surrounding code with your loop, youre not looping through your results correctly it should look something like this:

```
if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
  while(false !== ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    // your output logic
  }
}
```

Lastly you are using an undefined variable `$row2`... i only see `$row` being assigned in your code:

```
echo "                  
                <h2 style='margin:0; padding:0;'>Recent Comments</h2>
                <div class='comment'>by Anonymous on {$row2['date']}: <br> {$row2['info']} </div>

                    <input type='text' id='addComment' name='addComment' />
                    ";
```